# jQuery select event Firefox VS IE

Tags: jquery, html

I would link a select event to my input, in Firefox this works perfect in IE it doesn't.
My code is as following:

```
jQuery().ready(function($) {
    $event = ($.browser.msie ? "click" : "select");
    $("input[name^='type[']").bind($event, autocompleteType);
    $("input[name^='vendor[']").bind($event, autocompleteVendor);
});

function autocompleteVendor() {
    alert("vendor");
}
function autocompleteType() {
    alert("type");
}
```

What is wrong? How can i fix this? And i don't want to use onChange event because that only triggers when you go out of the input field...

Thanks.

Comment: What IE version? Do you see any javascript error?

Comment: Which version of jQuery you are using?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to use this:

```
$event = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') ? "click" : "select");
```